# Operator== to compare two different classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I have these two classes: `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
//forward declaration for Bar
class Bar;

typedef enum Type { TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3 };

// My class Foo
class Foo
{ 
public:
    explicit Foo(Type fooType) 
        :mType(fooType) 
    {} 

    Type getFooType() const
    {
        return mType;
    }

inline bool operator==(const Bar& bar) { return (bar.getBarType() == mType); } //ERROR: error C2027: use of undefined type 'Bar'

private:
    Type mType; 
};

// My class Bar
class Bar
{ 
public:
    explicit Bar(Type barType) 
        :mType(barType) 
    {} 

    Type getBarType() const
    {
        return mType;
    }

private:
    Type mType; 
};
```

Now somewhere in my code, I want to compare two instances (one from the Foo and other from Bar class).
Like this:

```
if(myBar->getBarType() == myFoo->getFooType())
{
 //...
}
```

**QUESTION:**
I know that I need to implement operator== to allow this comparation.
So I've done as seen above...
And I get that error, despite the fact that I've made the forward declaration.
What am I missing here that allows me to compare using the operator== on both classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `operator==` after the `Bar` class definition, rather than in the `Foo` class.  Declare it in the class, but define it outside.

```
inline Foo::operator==(const Bar &bar) const { ... }
```

This won't quite help with your test above, since you have the `Bar` element on the left and the `Foo` on the right, so the `operator==` in Foo won't be considered.  Defining symetric global `operator==` functions would be useful.

```
inline bool operator==(const Bar &bar, const Foo &foo) { return foo == bar; }
```

Comment: Thank you. But using the symetric global operator== as you suggested, I get the error: binary 'operator ==' has too many parameters. How can I overload the operator== with 2 parameters?

Comment: @waas1919 put it outside of any class

Answer (score 1):

You say you want this comparison to work...

```
if(myBar->getBarType() == myFoo->getFooType())
```

That's comparing the `enum Type` values returned by the `getXType` functions, not the `Foo` and `Bar` objects themselves, and enums are comparable by default so you don't need to provide your own `operator==`.

Never-the-less, you have tried to do so, and in...

```
inline bool operator==(const Bar& bar) { return (bar.getBarType() == mType); } //ERROR: error C2027: use of undefined type 'Bar'
```

...the problem is that `Bar` is not defined at the place this function definition appears in the translation unit.  You could just declare the function...

```
inline bool operator==(const Bar& bar);
```

...then define it later in the translation unit, after the definition of `class Bar`.

This would still only allow you to omit the explicit `getFooType()` call when comparing with a `Foo` as the left-hand-side argument and a `Bar` at right.  To support the other ordering you asked for, you'd need a similar operator inside `Bar` that worked with a `const Foo&`.

One more detail... you say...

> And I get that error, despite the fact that I've made the forward declaration.

A forward declaration just lets the compile know that `Bar` is a class, it doesn't tell the compiler that `Bar` contains a `Type getBarType()` member function, and that knowledge is needed to compile your `operator==`.